A regular expression for finding numbers and spaces in a specific configuration
A regular expression is required, which must find a sequence of 12 numbers, between which there can be no more than 2 spaces (not newlines) inside. Here are examples:
Example 1:3345624 90812
Example 2:908 7865123 23
Example 3:908765312334
Example 4:90878903556 1
Example 5:67555123452  5

An example of an invalid pattern is /[0-9|\s]{12,14}/, it allows trailing spaces, single spaces, newlines or alternating spaces and numbers.

Please edit question to make sure what Fredrich changed matches your input (it has newlines for example)

Take a look in [tag:regex]'s usage guide. Please [edit] and let us know which language/regex engine you're using.

@AllanWind I understood the examples to be comma-separated and edited for each one to be on a line of its own. Each line is twelve digits and one or two spaces. I might have been mistaken, of course.

@Friedrich Just to be clear no disrespect was intended.

I would do [\d ]{12,14} then see if you have at most 2 white space or 12 numbers in the result in calling code.  white space is space, form-feed, newline, carriage return, horizon table, and vertical tab.  You may mean space.

You probably want ^(?=(?:\D*\d){12,14}\D*$)\d+(?:\s{0,2}\d+)*$. See the regex demo at https://regex101.com/r/kHMqbf/1

If it is difficult, please give an example for 4 numbers with 1 or 2 spaces inside, I will scale up to 12.

I mean whitespace = space. It is the longest key on the keyboard.

Edit question to use the word space instead of whitespaces.

@WiktorStribiżew Neat.  It incorrectly matches "675551234520  5" (13 numbers).

@AllanWind Not sure what is correct, I see {12,14} in the original regex. If OP needs exactly 12 digits, just replace the quantifier, ^(?=(?:\D*\d){12}\D*$)\d+(?:\s{0,2}\d+)*$

@WiktorStribiżew I have been playing with the link you posted, and I can't the positive look-head working as expected.  ^(?=.{12,14})\d+ will match any number of digits but expect it only match at most 14.  grep seems to limit it to 14 as expected.

@AllanWind It is not a Bash pattern. It is an NFA compliant regex.

@WiktorStribiżew My point was that it didn't work in the regex tool you posted.

@AllanWind It is correct. There are 12 digits.

@WiktorStribiżew ... and 4 spaces (I know hard to see).  What about ^(?=(?: {0,2}\d){12} {0,2}$)(\d+|\d+ +\d+|\d+ \d+ \d+)$?

@AllanWind I understand from the question there can be 0-2 spaces between each digit

@WiktorStribiżew 2 spaces total is how I read it.

Then just use ^(?=(?:\D*\d){12}\D*$)\d+(?:\s\d+){0,2}$

@WiktorStribiżew Fails on 01234678901  2 (two spaces).  You don't to solve this, btw,  was just curious if there was a way to get it working being so close.

@AllanWind It is still doable with ^(?=(?:\D*\d){12}\D*$)(?=(?:\S*\s){0,2}\S*$)\d+(?:\s+\d+)*$

Do you match full strings (from start to end) or want to extract such sequences from some text? For full matching consider ^(?!(?:\d* ){3}) *(?:\d *){12}$ Please also mention regex tool/environment you're using.

You could write a function to do it. Here's a C# version, but it would be trivial to port it to any language as it's only ifs and a for loop.
public static string? FindDigitsAndSpaces(string s, int nDigits, int nMaxSpaces)
  {
    if (s.Length < nDigits) return null;

    var curSpaces = 0;
    var curDigits = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
      var c = s[i];
      if (char.IsDigit(c)) curDigits++;
      else if (c == ' ')
      {
        if (curDigits > 0)
        {
          if (curSpaces == nMaxSpaces)
          {
            curSpaces = 0;
            curDigits = 0;
          }
          else
            curSpaces++;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        curSpaces = 0;
        curDigits = 0;
      }

      if (curDigits == nDigits)
      {
        return s.Substring(
          startIndex: i + 1 - (curDigits + curSpaces),
          length: curDigits + curSpaces);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

Here are my tests:
  [TestMethod]
  [DataRow("3345624 90812", "3345624 90812")]
  [DataRow("908 7865123 23", "908 7865123 23")]
  [DataRow("908765312334", "908765312334")]
  [DataRow("90878903556 1", "90878903556 1")]
  [DataRow("67555123452  5", "67555123452  5")]
  [DataRow("12345678901   67555123452  5", "67555123452  5")]
  [DataRow("  67555123452  5", "67555123452  5")]
  [DataRow("123 456 789 012   67555123452  5", "67555123452  5")]
  [DataRow("67555123452   5", null)]
  public void TestMethod1(string s, string? expected)
  {
    foreach (var prefix in new[] { null, "a", "abc" })
      foreach (var postfix in new[] { null, "a", "abc" })
      {
        s = prefix + s + postfix;
        var res = FindDigitsAndSpaces(s, 12, 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, res); 

      }
  }

